# Cannot resolve added property of model in views

Tags: django

In my `views.py` file, I filter objects from a model, and I add some properties to the objects to use them later in templates.

```
matches = Match.objects.filter(season=season_name).order_by("match_date")
team_list = Team.objects.filter(id__in=team_ids)

for team in team_list:
    home_matches = matches.filter(home_team=team)
    away_matches = matches.filter(away_team=team)
    team.sf = len(Shot.objects.filter(match__in=matches, team=team))
    team.sa = len(Shot.objects.filter(match__in=matches, opponent_team=team))
    team.pdo = ((team.f / team.sf) + (1 - (team.a / team.sa))) * 1000
    team.xpdo = ((team.xgf / team.sf) + (1 - (team.xga / team.sa))) * 1000
```

For example, in my team model, fields sf, sa, pdo and xpdo does not exist. I calculate those fields on views and use them in a table in my template. There is no problem until here, actually. What I am trying to do is dumping query set as JSON and passing it the template to use in JavaScript.

```
context["teams_json"] = json.dumps(list(team_list.values_list(
        "team_name", "pdo", "xpdo")), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

When I run the server, I get the following error:

```
FieldError at /leagues/turkey2017/
Cannot resolve keyword 'pdo' into field. Choices are: away_team, home_team, id, opponent_team, passmaplineup, passmappass, player_stats_opponent_team, player_stats_team, shooter_team, team_dark_color, team_light_color, team_name
```

I see that choices are combination of original fields in my `Team` model and `ForeignKey` fields in other models such as this field in `Shot` model:

```
opponent_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="opponent_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I use the fields added in views later on in views again?

Comment: Perhaps `values_list` can only handle actual model fields?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `values_list` on something that is not a field. I suppose that the reason you are doing so is to remove unnecessary fields from your serialized data. But really using values_list at all here is overkill; you just have three bits of data, you could just as easily dump them manually:

```
data = [{'pdo': team.pdo, 'xpdo': team.xpdo, 'team_name': team.team_name} for team in team_list]
context["teams_json"] = json.dumps(data)
```